# After tarball restore my PC (tar xvfpz backup.tgz -C /), my sound card and network are not working. How to detect?

Tags: 12.04, tar

1 . I have a old laptop I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on. (It was ACER)

2 . I booted into single user mode and backed it up via

```
cd /
sudo -i
tar cvpzf backup.tgz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/dev --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/backup.tgz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys /
```

3 . I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 1204 on my new laptop (It is Dell)

4 . I boot into single user mode

5 . I backup the existing `/boot` directory

6 . I untar my backup to restore on to the Dell

```
sudo tar xvfpz backup.tgz -C /
```

7 . I restore the previous `/boot` directory again

8 . I boot it up, and my profile and settings are loaded ok but, Ubuntu shows that there is no Sound Card.. I cannot use unity to drag and change volume. I noticed that the network card also doesnt work.

** How do you make ubuntu recognize changed hardware, if the hardware is already configured for a different laptop? Does anyone know?**

Comment: [Troubleshoot Sound](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure), ... [Troubleshoot Wireless](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html)

Comment: I made a full tar backup of my old PC just like you. Then I booted my new pc and installed Ubuntu, then copied the tarbackup and untarred it. After Rebooting it didnt have SOUND also. And running `updatemanager` doesnt work either. I cannot get software updates on ubuntu anymore... I wonder why :(

Comment: Yes, I do not know why either :(

The **Ubuntu Help Pages** reccomend using a tarbackup, but it does not explain what to do, if after **untarring your backup .tgz** file how to fix unidentified devices.

Comment: I ficed it!!!! type this to reinstall drivers!!!

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: Well done for solving this - please can you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that this answer didnt solve my problem. Let me describe it carefully:

** Problem: Need to TARBALL BACKUP a old Laptop with old Hardware, and restore the entire OS onto a new laptop with LVM Enabled **

Here are my steps, but they DO NOT WORK if your laptop backup has a different kernel then the one that came on the Ubuntu CD (In other words I can only boot into the kernel in the tarball, to mount the lvm, but the other kernels will not work)

---

To backup: (MAKE SURE YOUR VERSION OF LINUX IS ONE LESS THAN THE LATEST IN THE DIST UGPRADE :(...)

1. BOOT INTO RECORVERY (HOLD SHIFT FOR GRUB OPTIONS on bootup)
   boot into recovery (use the grub recovery option, or single mode)
   unmount all harddrives other than sda1 which has your root OS

2.
cd /
sudo tar cvpzf backup.tgz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/dev --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/backup.tgz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys /

To restore:
0. Install a fresh Ubuntu (even the server or alternate cd with lvm WILL WORK WITH THIS). Do a regular install, settings dont matter because we will wipe it all away.

1. BOOT INTO RECORVERY (HOLD SHIFT FOR GRUB OPTIONS on bootup)

2.
backup your /boot carefully just in case!!! I do: cd /boot; mkdir ORIG.BOOT; mv * ORIG.boot; 
cd /
sudo tar xvfpz backup.tgz -C /

3.
THEN REVERT BACK TO YOUR ORINGAL BOOT (remember to MV not just tar ok???? and make sure the vmlinuz and initrd of the both are merged. and if u want its ok to... merge the grub.cfg too

1. After it boots  if you dont have sound or network run:
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get --reinstall dist-upgrade

   > > I tried this but it will only work with my old kernel in /boot, none of the new kernels (even after dist-upgrade will boot into the lvm properly)

Here is my grub.cfg, why doesnt it work?

#

## DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE

#

## It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates

## from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub

#

#### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header

if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 015c0470-4ba2-41aa-a140-181b1cc872c2
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 015c0470-4ba2-41aa-a140-181b1cc872c2
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=ja_JP
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi

#### END /etc/grub.d/00_header

#### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

#### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme

#### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux

function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="$1"
    if [ "$1" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ ${recordfail} != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "$linux_gfx_mode" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 015c0470-4ba2-41aa-a140-181b1cc872c2
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae root=UUID=015c0470-4ba2-41aa-a140-181b1cc872c2 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 015c0470-4ba2-41aa-a140-181b1cc872c2
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae root=UUID=015c0470-4ba2-41aa-a140-181b1cc872c2 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
}
submenu "Previous Linux versions" {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae --THIS IS THE ONLY KERNEL VERSION THAT WORKS' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 015c0470-4ba2-41aa-a140-181b1cc872c2
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae root=UUID=015c0470-4ba2-41aa-a140-181b1cc872c2 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae (recovery mode) --THIS IS THE ONLY KERNEL VERSION THAT WORKS' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 015c0470-4ba2-41aa-a140-181b1cc872c2
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae root=UUID=015c0470-4ba2-41aa-a140-181b1cc872c2 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
}
}

#### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux

#### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen

#### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen

#### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+

menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 015c0470-4ba2-41aa-a140-181b1cc872c2
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 015c0470-4ba2-41aa-a140-181b1cc872c2
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}

#### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+

#### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober

if [ "x${timeout}" != "x-1" ]; then
  if keystatus; then
    if keystatus --shift; then
      set timeout=-1
    else
      set timeout=0
    fi
  else
    if sleep --interruptible 3 ; then
      set timeout=0
    fi
  fi
fi

#### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober

#### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom

## This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the

## menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change

## the 'exec tail' line above.

#### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom

#### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom

if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi

#### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom